# QObject::findChildren() for QML object finding

Tags: qml, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

I have an QML form with `QQuickApplicationWindow`. I need to get `QQuickItem` pointers on `BaseKey` elements of QtVirtualKeyboard (it's implementation is placed in separate QML file and loads with Loader of layout when program executes), but it has dynamical (runtime) type like this BaseKey_QMLTYPE_XX, where "XX" is a changeable number.

I found `QObject::findChildren()` function http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild, but i cant find out number "XX" in typename.

How can i find QQuickItem pointer on BaseKey from C++ code?

Comment: `QObject::findChildren()` searches by `objectName` if that was your question.

Comment: @folibis, you are right, but how can I find out object name, if it has run-time dependency part -index number?

Comment: Are you trying to test an application that uses the virtual keyboard, or?

Comment: @Mitch I tried get button coordinates and emit keypress event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseKey_QMLTYPE_XX` looks like what you'd get if you printed the object (`print(myObject)`). I think that comes from [`QMetaObject::className()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#className).

If the object doesn't have an `objectName` set, you won't be able to find it using `findChild()` (unless you have access to the C++ type and there's only one object of that type).

I have a [hacky test helper function](https://github.com/mitchcurtis/slate/blob/41370962a280e5657782fbf67cb2bc19f3dba8b4/tests/shared/testhelper.cpp#L1951) that does something similar to what you're after:

```
QObject *TestHelper::findPopupFromTypeName(const QString &typeName) const
{
    QObject *popup = nullptr;
    foreach (QQuickItem *child, overlay->childItems()) {
        if (QString::fromLatin1(child->metaObject()->className()) == "QQuickPopupItem") {
            if (QString::fromLatin1(child->parent()->metaObject()->className()).contains(typeName)) {
                popup = child->parent();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return popup;
}
```

You could adapt this to iterate over the children of an object that you pass in. There are a couple more changes than that to get it to work, but the general idea is there.

Comment: Links are out of date: https://github.com/mitchcurtis/slate/blob/41370962a280e5657782fbf67cb2bc19f3dba8b4/tests/shared/testhelper.cpp#L1951 Note the overlay QQuickItem* must be initialized after the Window is open: https://github.com/mitchcurtis/slate/blob/41370962a280e5657782fbf67cb2bc19f3dba8b4/tests/shared/testhelper.cpp#L71